# How to explain about android(myapplication) application architecture?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application called calculator.In which I have different methods like add(),subtract(),Multiply() and etc.Someone ask me "What is the architecture of your calculator app?".What are the things should I want to tell for above question?

Comment: the answer is: do your homework yourself, ok?

Comment: have you google it??

Comment: Yes.I googled.But there are telling about android operating system architecture.

Comment: You can tell me ,some website or solution.Otherwise simply leave it.

Comment: its means classes you have used in your app.what they do? the sequence in which they get called..in short workflow of your apllications functionality

Comment: What is the architecture of your calculator app? & title of question have :-android application architecture?  What do you want exactly? Please clarify.

Comment: Without seeing your whole app, no one but you will be able to answer what the architecture of your app is. I tend to use the model view controller (MVC) pattern, but there are others.

Comment: You can tell about the different components that define your whole application. For example, you must have defined different packages, like for activites, for mathematical calculation etc. Tell them how these components interact to give the desired result.

Comment: Your question is not fit for Stackoverflow, as "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_" (from [help/on-topic]).

Comment: About 380.000.000 result on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ARCHITECTURE+OF+APPLICATION&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=899&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo4fy457fJAhVMF5QKHVmfAk8Q_AUIBygB) like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658098.aspx

Comment: look at this tutorial... [android application architecture](http://android-by.blogspot.in/search/label/Android%20application%20architecture)

Comment: @sud,@aiRbornE,Your answers is what I was searching.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "architecture" of a software application is a broad question. It's usually asked by teachers an interviews that want to see how much design you put into an solution instead of just hacking it up.

Architecture can encompass any of the following - with some made up examples.

**The basics and the platform** -

> My calculator app is a full screen Android activity that was written
> in Java using Android APIs"
>
> My calculator app is an Android desktop widget
>
> My calculator app is really a web page hosted in the cloud. The Android app just hosts the web page.
>
> The application is written with Xamerin, so I can port it to iOS later.

**The coding language**

> The entire app was written in Java with Android APIs.
>
> The app had it's UI written in Java, but the calc engine itself was
> written in C. I used the Android NDK to compile the calculator engine.

**How you designed your code**

> The app uses an MVC design. The MainActivity class manages the display and buttons and talks to the Model which is my calculator engine.
>
> I have an Activity class that holds the button and register state of the simulated calculator.

**What you modeled your core algorithms on**

> I modeled a cheap desktop calculator with three virtual registers that serve as the input buffer, display, and operand.
>
> I used integer arithmetic and keep track of the decimal precision myself.
>
> I used a large number library so that my scientific calculator could do floating point math accurately for large numbers.

**Your own internal data structures and classes**

> I have an Activity class for the UI, a class for the calculator state, and another class to keep track of typing history.
>
> The app uses multiple threads to calculate the result faster.
>
> The calculator engine keeps a stack to emulate reverse polish notation, a linked list for holding the state of numbers on the display, and a hash table to user actions to code operations.

**Putting it all together**

Nothing explains software architecture better than a picture.  Either a data flow diagram which is simple boxes and lines.  Or a formal UML diagram to show your class hierarchy.